# No se puede modificar el archivo classes.php de la cache symfony

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony2, iis

Hola por favor necesito de su ayuda:

Tengo instalado IIS y PHP 5.4 y tengo un sistema desarrollado en symfony2, el iis y php funcionan bien e incluso ya tengo el pdo_sqlsrv habilitado para conexión entre php y sql server 2014 todo parece funcionar bien solo que cuando copie mi proyecto en symfony en la carpeta wwwroot del iis(agregando el sitio web en administrador de iis) esto para ejecutar el código, y me marca lo siguiente;

RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SYSTEMA/app/cache/dev/classes.php".

Ahí dice que no se puede escribir sobre el archivo pero ne he podido resolverlo porque ya asigne permisos a la carpeta para mi usuario lo cual se me hace absurdo si mi usuario es el administrador, pero bueno, y no se que mas intentar.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Intenta: borrar la cache posterior a cambiar los permisos de escritura. Reiniciar apache2 o el servidor php que utilices. Si no te funciona nada de lo anterior prueba a cambiar de usuario propietario con chown. Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el modo desarrollo para que symfony te chive el error.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta lo que paso fue que creo que IIS crea un usuario(IIS_IUSRS) y hay que asignarle permisos sobre las carpetas del proyecto para ese usuario, bueno eso es lo que hice y me funciono.

Comment: Me podrías ayudar con otra duda que tengo pero ahora de Symfony2?... Quiero crear un formulario de edición desde el Controller, este formulario es de una tabla con relación con otra, es decir mi tabla principal es orden_de_compra y la tabla con la que tiene relación se llama productos_en_orden, por lo cual para este formulario cree los campos de la tabla principal desde el controlador y para la tabla foragnea agrege un campo asi:

Comment: ->add('products', 'collection', array(
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference'   => false,
                'label' => false,
                "required" =>false,
                'type' => new ProductsERType()
            ))

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera porque no tengo un archivo entity para las tablas, desconozco porque no puedo modificar el ORM de Symfony para que tome en cuenta las nuevas tablas agregadas a la base en sql server sin afectar los registros que tengo ahorita y agregando los entities correspondientes, por eso estoy buscando la manera de hacerlo sin depender de un entity.

Comment: Lo que he logrado hacer es el formulario sin campos de la tabla foragnea, pero quiero que al mostrar el formulario ya tenga mostrados campos en el prototype

Comment: hola, te aconsejo abras una nueva pregunta y expongas lo que has expuesto aquí. De esa forma te podrán ayudar más personas con un título más descriptivo.